# How can I send an email to a 'Company' (or any other field) by default in Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, contacts

When you start typing in a name in the 'To' field in a new email the email address of said person will be automatically selected. However, this only works with the contact's First and Surname, is there a way of typing in any other piece of information such as 'Company' to get the autosuggest list of emails to send to?

There seems to be a way of manually filtering by clicking on the 'To' button, but that is not much of an improvement.

Reason: a client uses Outlook to email various people at various companies and cannot remember the employee's names, but do know the company, however simply typing in the company name yields no autosuggestion for contacts and makes it a time consuming task of searching for them manually.

Any way of customising how this behaves or any other suggestions / workarounds / something totally obvious? I don't really use Outlook so I don't know where to begin with something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Is the email message standardized? I work for a University and we send out monthly statements to (almost) the same people, so a [template email](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-an-email-message-template-HA101829163.aspx) was created.

If not, using Outlook's native search features can be cheap and simple. Try creating a New E-mail > Click on  the "To..." button > click the "Advanced Find" link > and type in the criteria to the right of "Company:". This will return all employee addresses with that company. Hopefully that's at least slightly easier!

Answer (score 0):

Add the name of the company to the name. For Example "Exxon John Smith", It's not the most elegant solution for your contacts, but it resolves the issue. I think newer versions of outlook (2013 and later) are better at this though